# How to find rpm prefix after installing the rpm package

Tags: rpm

I have installed a rpm package using command "rpm -ivvh --prefix=/home/mypkg package_name ".After installing i need to find the prefix value .How i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

a very stale thread, but I have an answer. I found it just by typing

```
# rpm --querytags
```

here's an example of the output:

```
# rpm -qa --queryformat '%{name}-%{version} %{instprefixes}\n' lgtoclnt

lgtoclnt-7.6.5 /usr
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -q --queryformat '%{INSTALLPREFIX}\n' package_name
```

for finding the different tags with `--queryformat` you can check [here](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-queryformat-tags.html).